# WooCommerce API- get option SKU from order

Tags: php, woocommerce-rest-api

Environment: php 7.2
API Client: wc-api-php

Is it possible to get the SKU for the options of line items?  Our products have three levels.  Image as a product, which has options for print or print and frame.  Both are also products.  The frame has color options (set using variations).  We have a SKU set for print, print and frame, and color options.

```
$client = new Client(url, key, secret);
$order = $client->get('orders/id');

foreach($order->line_items as $lineItem){
    foreach($lineItem->meta_data as $metaData){
        // Has id, key, value (no SKU)
    }
}
```

My understanding is that meta_data are the product options.  Since SKU is not there, does that mean that the API does not return the SKU for options?  Or am I looking in the wrong place?